# Unable to launch camera in android mobile

Tags: android, reactjs, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I'm using below code to launch the camera and gallery on both android and iPhone. But in android it just doesn't open camera, only gallery opens and no multiple selection, whereas same works fine in iPhone(Camera & Gallery launches + multiple selection of files ).

React-js snippet:

**Input className="div-border-style" accept='.jpg,.jpeg,.png,.pdf' capture inverted multiple fluid type='file' onChange={onChange_ImagePicker}/>**

Note: Its a MS teams app.

Need help..!

Comment: Please make sure you have allowed device permissions in your team app and app manifest as well  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/device-capabilities/native-device-permissions?tabs=mobile%2Cteamsjs-v2%2Cmobile1#manage-permissions

Comment: @Prasad-MSFT Thanks for the link..
I'm following the steps in the link but i'm unable to get the 'App permission' under setting. Is there anything specific we need to follow to get..?

1. Go to Settings > App Permissions. (Not getting this)

Mostly i get "ErrorCode: 1000App doesn't have sufficient permission to use this API" this is expected as we dint allow permissions..
looking for your response..!

Comment: We tried to allow permissions in Mobile device and are able to do so. Attaching screenshots for ref: 1. https://i.stack.imgur.com/ROGGf.png 2.https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aqfp5.png 3. https://i.stack.imgur.com/0o9an.png

Comment: There are no specific permissions required to enable these.

Comment: @Prasad-MSFT I'm trying as javascript code, can u please suggest me a reference for it..?

Comment: You can refer this sample: https://github.com/OfficeDev/Microsoft-Teams-Samples/tree/main/samples/tab-device-permissions/nodejs

Comment: Thanks @Prasad-MSFT

But the sample is only in typescript, can you please guide me with Javascript sample app.

Comment: There is no sample code available for JavaScript. It's in typescript only.

Answer (score 0):

Usuallly Camera permissions are required. Also to save the picture you will need Storage permissions.

Comment: Thanks for your response.
But then same code works on iPhone without any explicit app permissions. And as per my knowledge even accessing gallery needs user consent, but thats working fine. But only launching camera as an issue.